# Очистка файла после чтения

Tags: php

Допустим есть файл `text.txt`, как сделать чтобы после чтения файла его содержимое было очищено?

Comment: Удалите его http://php.net/manual/ru/function.unlink.php

Comment: надо просто перезаписать его после чтения любой пхпшной функцией, которая для этого подходит. например `file_put_contents('имя файла', '');`